# Image gets messed up while trying to add text PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm trying to add text to a predefined image, but have failed to do so.
The code I am using is the following:

```
<?php   
header("Content-type: image/png");
if(file_exists("stats_gen.png")){ unlink("stats_gen.png");} //delete old version
$string = "text";
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("stats.png");
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $string, $textcolor);
imagepng($im); //show the image for debug purposes
imagepng($im, "stats_gen.png"); //save the image
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

stats.png looks like this:
Oh, image format not supported. Well, this: http://lolmewn.nl/stats/stats.png and ends up like http://lolmewn.nl/stats/stats_gen.png which looks crap.
What am I doing wrong? Google doesn't seem to give any answers...

Comment: can you try removing the line `imagedestroy($im);`. The `imagepng()` function may not be done creating before you destroy it.

Comment: @TimJoyce Thank you for your reply. I've removed it, but the output is the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: just for debugging... do you get the same output when not adding the text and just duplicating the image? remove `imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $string, $textcolor);`. also, double check that the image being created is not being cached. Add a random string to the end `...png?321`

Comment: It looks like the output is also distorted when not adding text. I've tried removing the other variables, so that only $im and the imagepng() functions are left. Same output.

Comment: *ahem* I've removed the transparency from the background, and now it seems to not do this anymore. What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the image background un-transparent. Heh.